# How can I have zsh exclude certain commands from history?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

Like, say, those that include the word "production"?

Comment: In case you were like me looking for a way to mark a command/alias so that it is filtered out of history, `zsh` can optionally exclude some commands/aliases if they start with a space : https://superuser.com/q/352788/1067306

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function zshaddhistory() {
    emulate -L zsh
    if [[ $1 != *"production"* ]] ; then
        print -sr -- "${1%%$'\n'}"
        fc -p
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Put the above to a file that will be sourced when interactive shell starts (to `.zshrc` or to a file that is sourced from `.zshrc` like I do).

Alternate form (implicit addition to history):

```
function zshaddhistory() {
    emulate -L zsh
    if [[ $1 = *"production"* ]] ; then
        return 1
    fi
}
```

. Note:

```
print -sr -- "${1%%$'\n'}"
```

explicitly adds item to history. But the same thing implicitly does zsh if `zshaddhistory` returns with zero exit code, so without `fc -p` and with `setopt nohistignoredups nohistignorealldups` (which is the default state) you will see unneeded duplicates in history.

`emulate -L zsh` is here to make sure that emulation settings does not step in and change the interpretation of the function body. I put this line at the start of the every function I define in zsh configuration.

Comment: this isn't working for me... i've tried many permutations. i've also tested that the branches are getting entered correctly (the `if` condition is correct). but the command still gets put into history. But this works: `zshaddhistory() { [[ $1 != *production* ]] }`

Comment: @John Bachir I made a mistake: I thought that `fc -p` is related to adding command to a history (and now unsure what is it doing here at all). Your variant works because according to the help `If any of the hook functions return a non-zero value the history line will not be saved, although it lingers in the history until the next line is executed allow you to reuse or edit it immediately.`.

Comment: Could you explain why you need the `print` and `fc` in the first place? I just tested it myself and it looks like the line (which triggered `zshaddhistory`s call) will be added to history automatically once this function returns 0.

Comment: @Julian It appears that you either need to remove those lines *or* use *both* `print -sr` and `fc -p`. `fc -p` *is* needed because otherwise `print` will produce a duplicate entry (which will then be removed by HIST_IGNORE_DUPS option if it is set, so you will not see it most of time). I.e. my code explicitly adds entry to the history, removing it or replacing with `return 0` will do just the same thing implicitly.

Comment: @Julian I updated the answer with more explanations.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the 'r' command (as it doesn't do anything but repeats the last cmd), but this is not working for me. I replaced the str with 'r' and removed the stars..

Comment: @Rainy You are probably missing LF, there is a reason my first function contains `${1%%$'\n'}`.

Comment: @ZyX, no - I pasted it exactly like you have it:

# exclude 'r' cmd from history
function zshaddhistory() {
    emulate -L zsh
    if [[ $1 != "r" ]] ; then
        print -sr -- "${1%%$'\n'}"
        fc -p
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

(SO doesn't format it properly in comment but it's pasted directly from your answer)

Comment: @Rainy You have missed the point. `$1` *ends with* `\n`, so matching `$1` against `r` will fail because it is never equal to *just* `r`. Asterisks covered that, your code does not.